# Lyx not compiling on new install on mac

Tags: lyx, compiling, installing

I haven't used lyx in years, but have some old files I would like to edit and compile. To be safe, I uninstalled lyx from my machine and reinstalled. I am using Mac OS Ventura 13.0. I followed the instructions here: https://wiki.lyx.org/Mac/Mac. I have lyx ver 2.3.7, Python 3.12.2, and the most recent version of MacTex. All my packages are updated in Tex Live Utility. However, when I try to compile the Introduction document in lyx, under the help file, it will not compile and returns multiple errors (shown in screen shot below). I feel like there is a simple solution, but despite many searches for an hour, I cannot find it. I suspect that lyx simply is not looking in the correct location, but I cannot figure out how to correct it. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: A MWE that reproduces the errors would be more helpful than a screenshot of errors.

Comment: I appreciate that a MWE would be helpful, but since it seems to be an error in the install, I'm not sure how to provide one. Essentially, I open the Introduction document under the Help menu in Lyx, I click compile, and I get the errors. If you have a suggestion on how I can generate a MWE beyond that description, I'm happy to oblige.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this one out on my own. I had to change the PATH prefix in Lyx and point it to the texbin. In Lyx select Preferences -- Paths. In the
"PATH prefix:" section I pointed it to "/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/universal-darwin".

Everything seems to be compiling correctly now.